# AngularJS GET Request with Parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, wordpress

I'm working on a project wherein Analytics from a WordPress Site need to be requested in an App via AngularJS GET Function. I want to filter out data from the JSON API. Can someone please help me with the Code?

JSON: http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-json/llama/v1/stats

I need to display the "label" , "data" as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday...

Here's what I've done until now:

```
<html ng-app="countryApp">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Angular.js JSON Fetching Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>

  var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);

  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

    $http.get('http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-json/llama/v1/stats').success(function(data) {

      $scope.countries = data;

    });

  });

</script>
```

Comment: I need to display the "label" , "data" as Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday... what does this mean with reference to the ajax data

Comment: The Content must get filtered out from the Ajax Data

Comment: But there is no **Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday** in your response, so we are not getting what you exactly want

Comment: There are 7 datasets, each represents Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.... So, if first data set is 0, then monday is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the dates are provided in the `labels` array, you could transform the `data` arrays with something like this

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    var visitDates = response.data.visits.labels.map(function(dateString) {
        return new Date(dateString);
    });

    $scope.visits = response.data.visits.datasets;

    angular.forEach($scope.visits, function(dataSet) {
        dataSet.data = dataSet.data.map(function(count, i) {
            return {
                date: visitDates[i],
                count: count
            };
        });
    });
})
```

Then, each `data` entry will have a `date` that you can pass through [Angular's *date* filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

```
<div ng-repeat="dataSet in visits">
    <h4>{{dataSet.label}}</h4>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="datum in dataSet.data">{{datum.date | date: 'EEEE'}} is {{datum.count | number}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you're not comfortable with using strings like "May 28, 2016" in the `Date` constructor, you could always use something like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to parse them.

Plunker demo ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/eXu6T8Zvr1fDjlGArFEY?p=preview

Comment: Ohh damn! thank you so much! Really appreciate your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

I checked the whole json data, there are no weekdays in it. please be clear about what you want as output. From your given code use data.data to get the actual json data returned from $http.get

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);

  countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){

    $http.get('http://happyshappy.13llama.com/wp-json/llama/v1/stats').success(function(data) {

      $scope.countries = data.data;

    });

  });
```